# Python statsmodels.imputation.mice: shape mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

I try to use the [MICE module of statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/imputation.html) to impute my dataset. However, I keep getting errors over some dimension which I don't understand.

Reproducable code here:

```
# Impute missing values using MICE
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.imputation.mice as mice

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
ix = [(row, col) for row in range(df.shape[0]) for col in range(df.shape[1])]
for row, col in random.sample(ix, int(round(.1*len(ix)))):
    df.iat[row, col] = np.nan

imp = mice.MICEData(df)
imp.update_all(10)
```

And the error I get:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) 
could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a known bug: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4129 Looks like it was fixed in their source repo, but not released yet. You could try grabbing their master branch and installing manually: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html

Comment: Hi Chris, thx for your help! Spend quite some time on installing it from master branch, but failed to do so on my Windows system. It demands a specific version of VS C++ I think, looking at the error messages. Do you know if there are wheels or anything available, or any other way to ommit the dependency on C++?

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate. And I'm not familiar enough. You might want to contact the development team or submit a bug report?